# Adding more than one IP to sip.conf tcpbindaddr and udpbindaddr (Asterisk 1.8)

Tags: tcp, voip, asterisk, udp, sip

The defaults in the sample sip.conf under Asterisk1.8 contain `udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0` and `tcpbindaddr=0.0.0.0`. I want to bind the incoming `[foo]` extension to udp:192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0, the outgoing `[foo]` to tcp:192.168.3.3/255.255.255.0, the incoming `[bar]` to tcp:192.168.3.3/255.255.255.0, and the outgoing `[bar]` to udp:192.168.4.4/255.255.255.0.

The topology as follows:

Softphone(192.168.1.1 [foo]) udp-> asteriskserver_0(192.168.2.2) tcp-> another server(192.168.3.3) tcp-> asteriskserver_0(192.168.2.2) udp-> hardphone(192.168.4.4 [bar]).

My original question was 'how to set the `{udp,tcp}addr=` variable to handle more than one IPs', but the more general question is how to configure the sip.conf and the extensions.conf?

Comment: Why don't you simply enable routing? Surely that would be less difficult since you're using exclusively private addresses.

Comment: How can I set it explicitely? Or is it set internally?

Comment: Add a new question. Draw your network and ask how to set up routing. It's really off-topic (has nothing to do with asterisk).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand you. The network is working, capable to transfer UDP and TCP, firewalls are out of consideration. The only problem is solely with Asterisk.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if asterisk binds to 192.168.1.1 if hardphone can connect to 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk can bind to single ip or to all ip same port.
No other options.

If you expect different ports on different interfaces, you have setup more advanced(and much more complex) sip proxy, like opensips/kamailio.